# Test for zero datetime in SSIS Conditional Split

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

A value coming back from a DB2 query passes a zero date as 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000 and I am having a problem testing for this value in a Conditional Split condition.  I tried a few different things but either they stay red or cause an error when run.  I even tried testing for the date being less than the SQL start date.  Neither of these work.

```
(DT_Date)DRIVER_TERMDATE < (DT_DATE)"1753-1-1"

DRIVER_TERMDATE != "0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum date for the `DT_DATE` data type is 1899-12-30, which is after that date and trying to convert it to this data type will cause an error.  If you're importing the `DRIVER_TERMDATE` as text, trying adding a condition for this string, for example

```
DRIVER_TERMDATE == "0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
```

However it looks like you already tried checking to see if `DRIVER_TERMDATE` is not equal to this value, so see if trailing zeros are being removed during from the text during execution by right-clicking the output from the DB2 source, selecting Enable Data Viewer, and examining the data when the package runs.  Once you've confirmed the exact string that's being sent in, you can add a condition for this.

Comment: I copied the data from the Data Viewer to Excel and discovered there is a dash added between the date and time.  Odd, but it now appears to work.